# PHP (Between + Convert Date)

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou fazendo uma tela em *php* onde o usuário tem o filtro de data pra extrair um relatório do banco *SQL Server*, mas o *MySQL* apresenta a data padrão **mm/dd/yyyy**, e eu preciso que ele vire **dd/mm/yyyy** no `between`, alguém sabe como fazer essa conversão?

Segue a forma que tentei:

```
SELECT p.idProcesso, p.Usr_id, p.Usr_name
  , p.Usr_CPF, p.crd_snr, t.dsPunicao
  , convert(varchar, p.dtCadastro, 103)+' '+convert(varchar, p.dtCadastro, 108) dtCadastro
  , s.dsStatusProcesso
  , p.idStatusProcesso 
FROM tmProcesso AS p
INNER JOIN tcStatusProcesso as s 
   on p.idStatusProcesso = s.idStatusProcesso
INNER JOIN tcPunicao as t 
   on p.idPunicao = t.idPunicao
WHERE p.app_id = '$var_appid'
  and p.dtCadastro between CONVERT(VARCHAR, '$var_dtini', GETDATE(), 103) 
  and CONVERT(VARCHAR, '$var_dtfim', GETDATE(), 103)"
```

Não sei se esse jeito tá certo, gostaria de confirmar, se for muito óbvio, me perdoem.

Comment: No MySQL e PHP eu uso dessa forma para consultas com data, e funciona: DATE_FORMAT(r.DATA_SAIDA, '%d-%m-%Y') as data, onde a data no banco esta como mm/dd/yyyy e no select eu transformo para dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @LidianeFernandes É MySQL ou SQL Server? Você cita MySQL no texto mas as funções são do SQL Server. // Como está declarada a coluna `p.dtCadastro`? // O formato de `$var_dtfim` é dd/mm/aaaa?

Comment: @JoséDiz é SQL Server, MSSQL. O formato dela no banco é mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Corrigindo, ali em cima aparece MySQL mesmo, mas é MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter a data antes de passar para a consulta. por exemplo:

```
function convertDatetoSQL($date)
{
    $date = explode('/', $date);
    return $date[1] . '/' . $date[0] . '/'. $date[2];
}

$var_dtfim = convertDateToSQL($var_dtfim);
```

Com o `explode`você transforma a variável em array dizendo que o delimitador é o "/" a partir daí tudo que estiver entre "/" viram posições no array, assim você pode manipular a data da maneira que você quer.

O que você pode fazer também é trabalhar com o objeto `DateTime` do PHP, aí ficaria dessa maneira:

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $var_dtfim);
$var_dtfim = $newDate->format('m/d/Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Galera, acabei fuçando um pouco mais e deu certo de um jeito simples, vou colocar aqui pra caso alguém também tenha a dúvida:

```
   p.dtCadastro between convert(datetime, '$var_dtini', 103)
   and convert(datetime, '$var_dtfim', 103)
```

Obrigada pessoal!